# Using mean value theorem in infinity

Tags: calculus

i have problem like this: 
$\lim\limits_{x \to  ∞} f(x)\to 0$ and $f(1)=0$

prove that there can be a number like $c>1$ which ${f^\prime(c)=0}$
can I use the mean value theorem to solve this?
if yes how am I allowed to specify infinity as a point and if no what is the solution

Comment: Try to replace the limit by its epsilon-delta definition

Comment: No, the MVT applies to $f$ defined on $[a,b]$. What you're trying to prove here is an extension of Rolle's Theorem; you can prove it by modifying the proof of RT.

Comment: You could shift vertically, slightly, and use RT, provided the function is not identically 0.